# npm install showing vulnerabilities for which no fix is available

Tags: react-native

I am trying to npm install to fix dependencies issues but it shows vulnerabilities and asks t o run npm audit and when I run npm audit it tell that "no fix available"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7wto.png)

Answer (score 1):

These vulnerabilities have to be fixed by the authors of their respective packages. So no you won't be able to fix them with npm.

Comment: How can I fix them?

Comment: @MuneebAhmad like I said, you can't. The package authors have to fix them, you are free to offer your support to them by opening pull requests on the repositories.